# GPUImage. Application crashes when trying to save photo second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gpuimage

After I made `[_stillCamera pauseCameraCapture];` I want to save captured photo. Code:

```
[_stillCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:_filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedJPEG, NSError *error){

     [self savePhotoToAlbum:processedJPEG];
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"error")
     }
}];
```

In first time photo saved successfully. After this I didn't make `[_stillCamera resumeCameraCapture];`, but when I tap save button again my application crashes without any message. How can I solve this?

Comment: Enable an exception breakpoint and see where it crashes.

Comment: @Till at first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your content of the handler should look like this:

```
if (error)
    NSLog(@"error occured code = %d", error.code);
else
    [self savePhotoToAlbum:processedJPEG];
```

Comment: any errors, application crashes an `stillCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter` line.

Comment: Don't you get a stack backtrace of it?